# Visual Studio Code - Open all modified files

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

Is there a way to open all files which are modified e.g. all tracked files which are showing after I execute `git status`?

[image]

Comment: `git status --porcelain` gives machine usable output, but you'll likely need to filter the output by `M` and then cut out the directory path using something like `awk`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to execute this command from a shell:

```
code $(git diff --no-commit-id --name-only -r HEAD)
```

However, this opens a new instance of VSC. Use `-r` if you like to open it on an already open instance:

```
code $(git diff --no-commit-id --name-only -r HEAD) -r
```

> -r --reuse-window                 Force to open a file or folder in an already opened window.